# AutoMapper removes all elements from an ICollection<T> property of an EF core proxy entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

AutoMapper removes all elements from an ICollection property of an EF core proxy entity.

**Code to reproduce:**

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Initializa database
    var dbContext = new DatabaseContext();
    dbContext.ClearAll<Blog>();

    // Initialize mapper
    var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<BlogDto, Blog>().ForMember(b => b.Posts, opt => opt.Condition((bDto, b) => bDto.Posts != null));
        cfg.CreateMap<PostDto, Post>();
    }).CreateMapper();

    // Initialize seed data
    var blog = new Blog
    {
        Description = "Blog description",
        Posts = new[]
        {
            new Post
            {
                Text = "Testing text 1",
            },
            new Post
            {
                Text = "Testing text 2",
            },
        },
    };

    // Add blog
    blog = dbContext.Add(blog).Entity;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // Detach and find again to get proxy of blog
    dbContext.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Detached;
    blog = dbContext.Find<Blog>(blog.Id);

    // Update
    var blogDtoForUpdate = new BlogDto
    {
        Description = "Updated blog description",
        Posts = null,
    };

    // After this line the blog will have empty Posts (not null).
    mapper.Map(blogDtoForUpdate, blog);
}
```

**Expected results:**
The blog.Description is updated with a new value and the blog.Posts is same as before mapping.

**Actual results:**
The blog.Description is properly updated but the blog.Posts is empty list of posts.

**Note:**

1. If the mapper ignore the Condition, the blog.Posts would be null but they are empty.
2. When I set the breakpoint into the opt.Condition and check the parameter 'b' (which is the blog), the Posts are already empty.

Does somebody know why or how to achieve the expected results?

Comment: Check AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't solve the problem that the mapper somewhere clear the collection.

Comment: Actually that's the whole purpose of that package. You just need to do a little more research. There are many similar questions.